# Sort unique numbers with memory constraints

Tags: algorithm, sorting, bitmap

This is an interview question for which I found answer at many places. I must admit that I was unable to understand the solution, so I am posing the question here for help:

```
Given an array having 16000 unique integers, each lying within the range 1 to 20000, how
do u sort it. U can load only 1000 numbers at a time in memory.
```

Here is a solution I came across, but which I could not understand: http://www.careercup.com/question?id=23123665

Specific questions:

- How did the author choose '625'. I know 20000/32 is 625, but what is the logic behind it?
- How does the author use divide and modulus operations to sort the array?

Comment: The logic behind it is to have 20,000 bits

Comment: and divide and modulus are used to select bit n in the 625 element array.

Comment: I think the number 20000 in binary is 100111000100000 so it is 15 bits. If we take it as maximum, then to store 16000 numbers we need at maximum 16000 * 15 = 240000 bits.

If we use vector of integers, then we need a vector of size 240000 / 32 = 7500 integers for that.

I don't understand how author came to the solution, either. :)

Comment: Oh I see. I get it now. I think I just needed that little hint to get started thinking in the right direction. Thanks!

Comment: @user1737819 keep in mind, the numbers are unique. So we need just one bit (out of the 20000) to store a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linked solution is essentially storing a compact histogram of the list of numbers. Each histogram bucket only accepts one number, and the numbers are unique in the list, so the bucket only needs to count from 0 to 1 (one bit). So with one number per bucket, that's 20,000 buckets you need to store in memory.

You can pack 20,000 one bit buckets into 625 32-bit integers. You can think of the array of integers as a 2d array of one bit values, with 625 rows and 32 columns. To find the bucket for a particular number, take the number/32 to find the row, and the number%32 to find the column.

Once you go through and count the existence of the numbers in the list, your histogram can be written back out in order as the sorted list.